# Appending JS obj values into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, key-value

I have a [JavaScript object](https://jsfiddle.net/4faL9uvd/1/) and I'm trying to append each of its Course Titles into a modal that's cloned. Clicking on a Category (i.e. Animals) opens up a modal that shows the description for Animals, and clicking on a different Category shows a different description. What I want is for Animals to be clicked on and the courses "Horse", "Chipmunk", "Peregrine Falcon", etc. to show up in its modal.

I'm running into a few problems when I try to `console.log` the Courses so I can see them.

Doing this:

```
trainingCrs = _categories[0].Courses.results.map(x => x.Title) // Works but only shows the Course Titles associated with Animals, as expected with the [0]
```

But doing:

```
allTrain = _categories.Courses.results.map(x => x.Title) // Get an error saying 'results' are undefined
```

Is there a reason why `results` are coming up as undefined? I'm not sure why `_categories[0].Courses` works but `_categories.Courses` doesn't.

Here's how I'm appending the Descriptions and Titles into my divs:

```
axios.get([abs-url] + "/getByTitle('Categories')/items?$select=Title,Description,Courses/Title,SortOrder&$expand=Courses&$orderby=Title&$top=1000",
            {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include",
                mode: "no-cors",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                }
            }),
]).then(axios.spread((cat) => {
        _categories = cat.data.d.results;
    // irrelevant info here
        this.loadCategories();
    })).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });


loadCategories(){
        let categs = _categories,

            trainingCrs = _categories[0].Courses.results.map(x => x.Title)
            // allTrain = _categories.Courses.results.map(x => x.Title)
            console.log(trainingCrs);
            // console.log('allTrain' + allTrain);

        let catBoxElems = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
                catBoxElems += 
                "<div class='cat-box cat-num-" + i + "'data-target='#modal-id' data-toggle='modal' data-desc='" + categs[i].Description + "'data-crs='" + trainingCrs[i] + "'data-title='" + categs[i].Title + "'>" + catPic + "<br>" + categs[i].Title + "</div>";
            } // trainingCrs[i].Title returns 'undefined', trainingCrs[i] does nnothing

            $(document).find("#modal-id").off("shown.bs.modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
                $(document).find(".modal-title").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("title"));
                $(document).find(".category-desc").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("desc"));
                $(document).find(".training-titles-ul").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("crs")); // ------------------- //
            }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
                $(document).find(".modal-title").html("");
            });

        let container = document.querySelector("div.top-training");
        container.innerHTML = catBoxElems;
        console.log(container);

        $(".modal-img").append(catPic)
    }
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="category-desc">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="training-titles">
       <ul class="training-titles-ul"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `categories.map((cat) => cat.Courses.results.map(x => x.Title)).flat()`

Answer (score 2):

Its because `_categories` is an array of objects.  There is no property `results` on an array - just an the individual objects in the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).  Using an indexer like `[0]` selects the first item in the array so that you can then select the results property.

Depending on the source of the data or API you are retrieving the _categories from, it may be perfectly fine to always grab the first element/category.  Many API's return collections containing only one item that you then have to parse or step through to extract data.

### Simple example

```js
class Result {
 constructor(title) {
  this.Title = title
 }
}

class Category {
 constructor(category) {
  this.Category = category
  this.Results = []
 }
}
// create a sample category
const category1 = new Category("Test")

// add a fake result set
category1.Results.push(new Result("Result 1"))

// build an array to hold our sample objects
const _categories = []
_categories.push(category1)

// here is your _categories array 
console.log(_categories)

// notices how Results don't live on the array itself
console.log(_categories.Results)

// but Results do live on the first item in the array
console.log(_categories[0].Results)
```